# 2 folders division for codeigniter folders

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to divide my ci into two folders: admin and sites.  I wonder how to set the controllers where to pick at the first look.  And why it has to pick the site first and running the sites controllers at the first pick.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use HMVC https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc old tutorial but good https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8fy8E_C5_qQ

Comment: Or you can have look at http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html

Comment: Where can I find that $application_folder = 'application'; ?

Comment: Its in your site index.php file

Comment: Okay,  I try this:   masterlinkci/index.php

    $application_folder = 'application/site';

I wonder when I click masterlinkci/  I receive this error messages:

Warning: require_once(C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci\application\site\config/constants.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\masterlinkci\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 70

Comment: I am trying using HMVC and I get this error messages:  Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php  How to fix the error ?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do separation here by having a completely separate install of CI within a sub folder called 'admin'. Then the admin part of the site was completely seperate from the main site. This works very well, takes no special set ups and it means security for admin for authorisation and authentication can be set to be very strict on all pages within admin.

Nowdays if I were doing this, I would simply keep the admin controllers within the main site in their own folder. This is manageable now because the admin folder would only need a few controllers with most of the functionality within libraries where I can have as many sub folders in the folder structure as I need to keep the roles clean.

You can also run both parts of the seperate CI systems through a single index.php and a single install of CI, but personally I find that the complexity added by all the seperate settings for which set of views or controllers to call just a pain, especially for debugging.

If I were you, and this is your first time doing this, I would simply do two installs of CI. They can both use the same database quite easily and to set this up is just a case of a few minutes creating a sub folder and a new install.

Comment: I think I already try that thing.  I place admin and site inside application folder under masterlinkci folder.